# Should I write "who doesn't go" or "who don't go"?

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct?

> I am a food lover who **doesn't go** by the reputation of the food sellers.
>
> I am a food lover who **don't  go** by the reputation of the food sellers.

Help me either to use **doesn't or don't**

Comment: Similar: [Is it ok for me to switch from first person to third person here, or can I do this better in first person?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110291)

Comment: My problem with this question is that the sentence doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

"Someone who" is always followed by the third person singular of the verb, thus you must use 'does' or 'doesn't'. This is true even if the subject of the sentence is 'I'. I am a person who likes sailing. He is a person who eats cheese. You are a person who makes me happy. If the subject is plural, then the verb is the third person plural: they are people who like music.